# pattern match on a list to check empty

Tags: scala

I want to check if a list is empty using pattern matching

```
val simplelist: List[Char] = List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

def test(l:List[Char]):Unit= l.map(d => print(d))
simplelist match {
   case x :: xs =>
     test(xs)
   case Nil=>  log.info("empty")
}
```

Output is bcd and not abcd

Comment: Please read the documentation and understand what pattern matching is and how it works. I have the feeling that you did not understand what case x :: xs mean!

Answer (score 4):

You could try it as simple as:

```
scala> List(1,2).isEmpty
res0: Boolean = false
```

You do not need pattern matching for this.

Answer (score 3):

1. For Empty List pattern match, you can do this.

`val simplelist: List[Char] = List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`

```
def test(l:List[Char]):Unit= l.map(d => print(d))
simplelist match {
   case x :: xs =>
     test(xs)
   case List() => println("empty List") // this will pattern match as empty List
   case Nil=>  log.info("empty")
}
```

2) For the question, Output is bcd and not abcd

In case `x :: xs, List('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')` matches as 
x = 'a' and 
xs = List('b', 'c', 'd')

And you are passing only xs to test method. Hence it is printing only b,c,d as expected.

Comment: How does `x :: xs` set the first element as `x`?

Answer (score 1):

In the match expression, "x :: xs" matches Lists with a first element, which will be stored as "x", and a tail which will be stored as "xs". Then, you print the contents of "xs", so are passing only the tail of the list to test. It will match any list with a head element and a tail, including a -> Nil, a list of one element. In that example, "a" will be stored in x, and Nil will be stored in xs.

This will work if you try:

```
simplelist match {
    case Nil => log.info("empty")
    case x => test(x)
}
```

This will try to match the empty list, then match anything else and refer to it as x, and print the results. Because simplelist is definitely a List (and assuming you did not use null), the x will refer to a non-empty list, and you can call test(x).

It would also work to do

```
simplelist match {
    case x :: xs => test (simplelist)
    case Nil => log.info("empty")
}
```

which would match any list with a first element and a tail, but then pass simplelist to test.